# Can a graph of a function be rotated 90 degrees and represent the same function?

Tags: functions

I was looking at the following problem: "If a graph of a function rotated 90 degrees about the origin, then it is not changed. Is there such a function?" The only one I can think of if is $f(x)=0$ defined on $x=0$. Is it possible to prove that this is the only such function? I understand that due to the rotational symmetry $f(-f(x))=x$ but how do I go from here?

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, $f$ would have to be one-to-one, otherwise it would fail the vertical line test after rotation.

Comment: A necessary condition: $y=f(x)\iff f(-y)=x$

Comment: ajotatxe observation.  Will allow for a method of picking functions point by point.  $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x^2}; -1\le x < -1/2;0\le x < 12; f(x) = -\sqrt{1-x^2}$ otherwise, works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One example defined on all of $\mathbb R$ would be

[image: graph of the following function:]
$ \raise 5em \hbox{$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & x=0 \\
(-1)^{\lceil x\rceil}x -1 & x>0 \\
(-1)^{\lfloor x\rfloor}x+1 & x<0 \end{cases} $} $

*Bonus question:* Is there a solution with finitely many discontinuities? I can't find one.

Comment: .........Great!

Comment: @Henning Makholm. Thank you! The second part of the problem was "prove that $f(b)=b$ has a unique solution" but I think I can take care of that one now.

Answer (score 1):

To answer hmakholm left over Monica's question there is one example of such a function with a finite number of discontinuities:

$ \raise 3em \hbox{$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 
0 & x=0 \\
\tan{x}+\frac{\pi}{2} & 0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}\\
\tan(x)-\frac{\pi}{2}  & -\frac{\pi}{2} <x<0 \\
-\arctan(x-\frac{\pi}{2}) & \frac{\pi}{2} \leq x \\
-\arctan(x+\frac{\pi}{2}) & x \leq -\frac{\pi}{2} \\
\end{cases} $} $

https://m.imgur.com/a/llXgBXc

Comment: Rotating that by 90 degrees doesn't even give a function (and so in particular not itself) because it is not injective: $f(-\frac\pi2)=f(0)=f(\frac\pi2)=0$.

Comment: @hmakholmleftoverMonica Could $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $x=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ be excluded from the domain?